# How to write to file from different for loops to one f.write

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try this code with beautifulsoup but it duplicates the result over and over.

any idea how to use f.write with different for loops?

```html
jobs_title = soup.find_all('td', class_='coljobtitle')
jobs_city = soup.find_all('td', class_='colcity')
jobs_type = soup.find_all('td', class_='colshorttextfield3')



filename = 'test.csv'
f = open(filename, 'w')

headers = 'Title, City, Type \n'

f.write(headers)


  
   
for job in jobs_title:
    name = job.find('a').text.strip()
    # print(name)
    
    for job2 in jobs_city:
        city = job2.text.strip()
        # print(city)
        for job3 in jobs_type:
            jobtype = job3.text.strip()
            # print(jobtype)

        f.write(name + ',' + city + ',' + jobtype +'\n')
    

f.close()
```

Comment: I think you should give f.write one more tab. What I mean is that it is not in the last for loop like ```print(jobtype)``` is.

Comment: please provide the three list elements and the output you expect for others to be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are doing nested loops. What I would do is I would grab the parent element of those three elements, and iterate through those. Otherwise, **assuming** those lists are of equal length, you can pull the corresponding elements by the index value:

Another option is to use zip to combine each corresponding elements so that you iterate through them together.

```
jobs_title = soup.find_all('td', class_='coljobtitle')
jobs_city = soup.find_all('td', class_='colcity')
jobs_type = soup.find_all('td', class_='colshorttextfield3')



filename = 'test.csv'
f = open(filename, 'w')

headers = 'Title, City, Type \n'

f.write(headers)


  
   
for idx, job in enumerate(jobs_title):
    name = job.find('a').text.strip()
    # print(name)
    
    city = jobs_city[idx].text.strip()
    # print(city)
    

    jobtype = jobs_type[idx].text.strip()
    # print(jobtype)

    f.write(name + ',' + city + ',' + jobtype +'\n')
    

f.close()
```